# WSAStringToAddress thinks "1.2.3" is a valid IP address

Tags: c++, validation, ipv4

I need to check whether a string is a valid IPv4 address in a Windows C++ application.  The code I'm using is:

```
char *ipAddress = ... // get from user input
struct sockaddr_in sa;
int sizeof_sa = sizeof(sa);
int valid = WSAStringToAddressA(ipAddress, AF_INET,NULL, (LPSOCKADDR)&sa,&sizeof_sa);
```

If I enter "1.2.3" as the value of `ipAddress`, `WSAStringToAddressA` returns 0, indicating that it is a valid IPv4 address, when it is clearly only three octets.

Why does `WSAStringToAddressA` think "1.2.3" is a valid IPv4 address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it *is* a valid IPv4 address, as far as Microsoft's parsers are concerned.  The [`inet_addr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563.aspx) documentation explains this in more detail:

> Internet Addresses
>
> Values specified using the ".'' notation take one of the following forms:
>
> a.b.c.d **a.b.c** a.b a
>
> When four parts are specified, each is interpreted as a byte of data and assigned, from left to right, to the 4 bytes of an Internet address. When an Internet address is viewed as a 32-bit integer quantity on the Intel architecture, the bytes referred to above appear as "d.c.b.a''. That is, the bytes on an Intel processor are ordered from right to left.
>
> The parts that make up an address in "." notation can be decimal, octal or hexadecimal as specified in the C language. Numbers that start with "0x" or "0X" imply hexadecimal. Numbers that start with "0" imply octal. All other numbers are interpreted as decimal.
>
> ```
> Internet address value   Meaning
> "4.3.2.16"               Decimal 
> "004.003.002.020"        Octal 
> "0x4.0x3.0x2.0x10"       Hexadecimal 
> "4.003.002.0x10"         Mix
> ```
>
> The inet_addr function supports the decimal, octal, hexadecimal, and mixed notations for the string passed in the cp parameter.
>
> Note  The following notations are only used by Berkeley software, and nowhere else on the Internet. For compatibility with Berkeley software, the inet_addr function also supports the additional notations specified below.
>
> **When a three-part address is specified, the last part is interpreted as a 16-bit quantity and placed in the right-most 2 bytes of the network address. This makes the three-part address format convenient for specifying Class B network addresses as "128.net.host"**
>
> When a two-part address is specified, the last part is interpreted as a 24-bit quantity and placed in the right-most 3 bytes of the network address. This makes the two-part address format convenient for specifying Class A network addresses as "net.host''.
>
> When only one part is given, the value is stored directly in the network address without any byte rearrangement.